# Angular JS - How to monitor selection in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `select` to display dropdown . Now my requirement watch the selection in dropdown and modify the chart below this dropdown . When i log `selected` value inside the `onchange` event, it shows undefined .

**my.html**

```
  <select ng-change="selectAction()"  ng-model="myOption"
    ng-options="value.id as value.label group by value.group for value in myOptions">
    <option>--</option>
    </select>
```

**mycontroller.js**

```
data = {
        "myOptions": [
            {
                "id": 106,
                "group": "Group 1",
                "label": "Item 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 107,
                "group": "Group 1",
                "label": "Item 2"
            }]
        };
    $scope.myOptions = data.myOptions;
    $scope.selectAction = function() {
        console.log($scope.myOption);
    };
```

Comment: Working here http://jsfiddle.net/sailorob/2pRqz/

Comment: is that grouping a necessary . can i do it without  that

Comment: it's working fine in fiddle . but not in my application . what i am missing here.